# Saving input data in java desktop app to a file?

Tags: java, file, netbeans

I'm trying to make a program where it shows you statistics (Sort of like high-scores if not exactly) in Netbeans. Basicly what I'm asking is, how do you get some input that a user wrote (In a jTextField for example) and save that data to a file which can be openned later on? I'm basicly trying to make it so if you press a button it opens the file and shows you some statistics (For example if you typed in 5 values in 5 jTextFields pressing the statistics button will show those values). Any ideas? Also if you can, please supply me with some tutorials about java desktop application file handling, as I've been looking but found nothing concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking how to persist "some input".  How small is that "some input"?  A common way to deal with small inputs, like user preferences and "last entered" inputs and so on in desktop apps is to use the "Preferences" API.

Java 6 link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html

Java 7 link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html

It's a simple key/value pair that allows you to store data without needing to deal with the specificities of file system.

For more complicated needs you may want to deal with actual files but from your description the Preferences API may be what you're after.